# Reform pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame( { 
    "text" : ["Alice is in ", "Alice is in wonderland.", "Mallory has done the task.", "Mallory has", "Bob is final." , "Mallory has done"] , 
    "label" : ["Seattle", "Portlang", "Gotland", "california", "california", "Portland"] ,
    "title":["SA","SA","sometitle","sometitle","some different title","sometitle"],
    "version":[1,2,4,1,2,3]})

df1
              text                  label           title            version
    0   Alice is in                Seattle         SA                   1 
    1   Alice is in wonderland.    Portlang        SA                   2
    2   Mallory has done the task. Portland       sometitle             4
    3   Mallory has                california     sometitle             1
    4   Bob is final.              california     some different title  2
    5   Mallory has done            Portland       sometitle            3
```

I want to keep the title and text corresponding to the latest version number, also want to keep the labels in a list.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.merge` with `Groupby.agg`:

```
In [508]: x = df1.groupby(['title']).agg({'version':'max', 'label':list})

In [516]: df1[['title', 'version', 'text']].merge(x, on=['title', 'version'])
Out[516]: 
                  title  version                        text                            label
0                    SA        2     Alice is in wonderland.              [Seattle, Portlang]
1             sometitle        4  Mallory has done the task.  [Gotland, california, Portland]
2  some different title        2               Bob is final.                     [california]
```

Comment: thank you:) its pretty close, I still miss the list of my label.

Comment: @Violet Please check now.

Comment: thank you :) that's exactly what I want.

Comment: `code`                                                                                                                                                                   
        text                   Seattle    Portlang    Gotland  california  Portland
0     Alice is in wonderland.         1         1           0       0           0
1     Mallory has done the task.      0         0           1       1           1
2     Bob is final.                   0         0           0       0           1
`code`
Hi @mayank,the requirement has changed & I need the following data-format. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Violet Hi. It's better to post a new question with new requirement.